# Как убрать действие кнопки в telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Суть такова
Я хочу чтобы при нажатии на кнопку человеку присылались сообщение и выполнялось register_next_step_handler.
Как сделать так чтобы кнопка не работала когда уже в register.

Если юзер нажмёт кнопку 2 раза то будет так

> Введите текст

> Введите текст

Он пишет текст

> Привет

Бот присылает ответ

> Ваш текст - Привет

> Ваш текст - Привет

Как сделать чтобы когда пользователь вот так 2 раза нажал не происходило 2 сообщения

Comment: не использовать телебот, а взять аиограм и фсм

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант - создать переменную-флаг, которая будет игнорировать двойные нажатия на кнопку.

Пример кода:

```
import telebot
from telebot import types

bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')
is_processing_command = False

markup = types.ReplyKeyboardMarkup(resize_keyboard=True)
item1 = types.KeyboardButton("click")
markup.row(item1)


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == "/start")
def notification(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "click on button", reply_markup=markup)


@bot.message_handler(func=lambda message: message.text == "click" and message.chat.type == 'private')
def par(message):
    global is_processing_command
    if not is_processing_command:
        is_processing_command = True
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "enter text!", reply_markup=markup)
        bot.register_next_step_handler(message, send)


def send(message):
    global mess, is_processing_command
    mess = message.text
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, "you wrote: " + mess, reply_markup=markup)
    is_processing_command = False


bot.infinity_polling()
```